# Searching for a document in a library that has a space in the library name not working

Tags: search-results, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a problem I am trying to figure out with the search API. Most of the time the file names are unique, but every once and a while there are two or more files in different libraries on the site with the same name. So in order to get the right file, we us the "path:" property in the REST call to narrow down the search to specific libraries.

However, I have noticed a problem when the library name has a space in it.  If I use the "path:" property to search a library called ArchiveData (no spaces) the search works just fine and pulls back the document I need.  However, if the library name is "Current Data" (with a space) then I get no files back.

So:

```
https://<site>/_api/search/query?querytext = '(Document.doc)+AND+(path:https://<site>/ArchiveData/'
```

will return one document from this library.

This URL however doesn't return any hits:

```
 https://<site>/_api/search/query?querytext='(Document.doc)+AND+(path:https://<site>/Current Data/'
```

Doesn't work and I get no document.  I have tried to escape the space with %20 in the library name with no luck.  Can someone tell me how to encode the path for a library that has spaces in the name?

I also noticed in some of the libraries that we have that have dashes in the name the dash is replaced with a space, so it too fails in the "path:"

Thanks.

Comment: Try replacing space by  `_x0020_`  ` https://<site>/_api/search/query?querytext='(Document.doc)+AND+(path:https://<site>/Current_x0020_Data/'`

Comment: Already tried this, as well as URLEncoding the string too.  No luck.

Comment: Try 'path:"https://foo/bar/shared documents"' put the full path in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ran into similar issues after a re-provision of the search service. After spending significant time on the phone with Microsoft, we found including a non-default zone in our list of content sources was causing this issue.

Please see the following:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_strategery/2014/07/08/problems-crawling-the-non-default-zone-explained/

http://sharepointfarmer.com/inplace-search-on-document-libraries-and-lists-is-not-working/

In our case we were attempting to use the server name we all knew, but was not the actual name of the default zone as listed in CA > System Settings > Alternate Access Mappings. Adding the default zone was not enough, we needed to remove the intranet and custom zones from the list under CA > Service Applications > Manage Service Applications > *Search Service Application Name* (not the proxy) > Content Sources > *name (ours is Local SharePoint sites)* > Start Addresses > List of URLs . 
After removal of all non-default zones, we ran a full crawl to resolve our particular no-search-links-with-spaces issue. 
I hope this helps.

Warren

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Matthew McDermott's comment i solved the problem;
So just put the path in quotes e.g. (when there are more than one path):

```
"xxx/_api/search/query?querytext='test+AND+(path:<pathWithoutSpace>+OR+path:\"<pathWith Space>\")'"
```